Docker bridge network breaks local internet
On a fresh install of ubuntu-server v24.04 and docker-ce v27.4.1, if I run any docker container with bridge network it breaks the whole local internet after 2-3s. I've checked my docker0 bridge network is unmamanged. Everything seems fine to me, if I ping google.com from docker it shows 66% packet loss.
docker run -it --rm busybox ping -c3 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.196.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.196.110: seq=0 ttl=53 time=55.065 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 66% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 55.065/55.065/55.065 ms

networkctl output:
IDX LINK    TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo      loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp37s0 ether    routable    configured
  3 docker0 bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged

ip route:
default via 10.12.0.1 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp src 10.12.0.10 metric 100 
1.1.1.1 via 10.12.0.1 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp src 10.12.0.10 metric 100 
10.12.0.0/24 dev enp37s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.12.0.10 metric 100 
10.12.0.1 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.12.0.10 metric 100 
10.12.0.10 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp scope host src 10.12.0.10 metric 100 
172.16.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1 linkdown 

iptables:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere   


You can check if it is a IP/subnet conflicts, lets try if changing the docker default subnet fix your problem
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "bip": "172.31.0.1/24"
}
EOF

sudo systemctl restart docker

then run the container again
docker run -it --rm busybox ping -c 3 google.com

if this still doesnt work you can try flushing the iptables rules, dont try this if you are on a production server because it can lock you out
# Save existing rules just in case
sudo iptables-save > /root/iptables-backup-$(date +%s).txt

# Flush/filter all existing rules
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -X

# Set default policies to ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Try pinging from within Docker
docker run --rm busybox ping -c 3 google.com


Thank you, but this solution not working for me. I have tried setting bip and flushing the iptables. after flushing iptables I got ping: bad address 'google.com' , I have also tried adding dns in /etc/docker/daemon.json, still not working..

you can try with known DNS like 8.8.8.8 or 9.9.9.9 in /etc/resolv.conf

no working as well.. still getting bad address 'google.com'
